# Implementing logging with messages not constructed when severity is low

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm wondering if there is any way to assure that messages that are defined in logging line are not constructed. There are some cases that I would add logging with 'trace' severity but I'm concerned about messages beeing constructed anyway (no matter if severity is high or low). Let's consider follwing simplified logging system:

```
template<class... Msg>
void logMessage(LogLevel logLevel, Msg... msg) {
    if (logLevel == LogLevel::Info) {
        auto test = fmt::format(std::forward<Msg>(msg)...);
    }
}
```

With client calls:

```
logMessage(LogLevel::Info, "this is sample message: {}", 123);
```

As I undestand there is no guarantee even when log level is not equal to 'Info' that compiler will optimize this out. So there is no guarantee that "this is sample message: {}" string is not constructed as temporary, rvalue variable.
The only way to achieve the goal would be:

```
template<class... Msg>
void logMessage(Msg... msg) {
    auto test = fmt::format(std::forward<Msg>(msg)...);
}
```

But each client calls would look like this:

```
LogLevel level = LogLevel::Info;
if (level == LogLevel::Debug) {
    logMessage("this is sample message: {}", 123);
}
```

I'm wondering if there is any clever way of Macros usage or constexpr in order to have clean, one line logging API and at the same time assuring that when severity is low then even parameters are not constructed? (Severity will still need to be configured at runtime)

Comment: `"this is sample message: {}"` is just a string literal, no string is "constructed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preamble**: I think this is a *bad idea*. The execution order of expressions is a core fundamental property of the language, and messing with that in a transparent way for the sake of saving a few lines of code is just asking for surprises, unexpected program behavior and superfluous cognitive load.

That being said, should you want to go down that path regardless, the macro required to get the behavior you want is not particularly complicated:

```
#define logMessage(level, ...) \
  if(level >= gCurrentLogLevel) logMessageImpl(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Usage:

```
int bar();

void foo() {
  logMessage(LogLevel::Info, "Some message: {}", bar());
}
```

In this scenario, for better or worse, `bar()` will only ever be called if `gCurrentLogLevel` is at least `LogLevel::Info`.

Comment: Thanks. Considering that calling a function directly in logging message line could be banned in a project then no high risk I could see at first point. Anyway asserts calls have the same consideration so no big surprise for developers would be the same idea I believe.

Comment: @AdamStepniak And that's why many organizations use an alternate `assert()` that void-casts the result of the expression in release builds.